# Renaming files that are about to be overwritten by an RPM?

Tags: rpm

I've got an RPM that overlays particular files delivered by another package. What I'd like to do is tell RPM "if 'directory/file' exists *and you're about to overwrite it*, rename it to "filename.backup" first.

It doesn't look like %pre gets to know which %files are delivered by the RPM. Is there a way or keeping backups of original files that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea.  What happens when the initial package gets updated?  Your changes are likely to get reverted.

I'd try to repackage the initial package with your edits versus trying to fold another package on top of the original.

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question directly but something for you to consider.

See also, config files, noreplace, etc:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingGuidelines#Configuration_files